# In Gmail. how may I directly forward multiple mails into an existing message being composed?

Tags: gmail

I am in a compose window. I want to forward multiple existing mails in this composed message, without having save on local computer. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpted from [Gmail: Intermediate tips Forward an email as an attachment](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9696522?hl=en)

### Forward multiple emails as attachments

1. Open Gmail.
2. Click Compose.
3. Check the boxes next to the messages that you want to attach and drag them to the new message window.
4. Enter a recipient, subject, and any message text.
5. Click Send.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks mostly worked. On about half the attempts, the drop failed to attach, and instead the "Move n conversations" tip slid back to the message list. The rest of the attempts succeeded. Also I note that this meets the requirement only when the desired mails are all of one or more conversations. Workaround: switch off Conversation view.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I can't say why you are experiencing the 'drop'.  If I was to guess you are using a touchpad on a laptop or something.  I understand your frustration but there are limitations to the user experience in a custom web app.  On a PC, there is a lot of core functionality like dragging and dropping that is shared across all apps out of the gate. 
 Web apps need to recreate this on top of the basic web browser functions.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm using a mouse. If there's a key alternative for this command, please do tell.

Comment: I found it fussy as well.  If it fails sometimes but is used infrequently may not be worth much more effort.  How frequently do you forward multiple individual  messages as attachments?

Comment: "Workaround: switch off Conversation view. " This fails when there's a draft reply: https://i.imgur.com/hyQUuNu.png

Comment: Note: Here, the drag shows a bogus "Label" tooltip: https://i.imgur.com/ncfS08Z.png .

Comment: "This fails when there's a draft reply" ... with Gmail falsely claiming the email "contains" a draft. Goodness.

Comment: "Workaround: switch off Conversation view. " "Here, the drag shows a bogus "Label" tooltip: i.imgur.com/ncfS08Z.pn" ... which also falsely states what's being attached are /conversations/ whereas they are just individual messages.

Comment: "Check the boxes next to the messages that you want to attach" is redundant here. The subsequent drag sets the checkbox as a side effect (!).

Comment: @ChrisJJ I don't understand.  How do you drag multiple messages if they are not first selected?