# In Gmail. how may I directly forward a subset of a conversation's messages into an existing message being composed?

Tags: gmail

I am in a compose window. I want to forward a subset of another conversation's messages in this composed message. How?

Currently the best I can find is to individually forward, cut, delete and paste - provided there's no reply being composed there already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Gmail. how may I directly forward multiple mails into an existing message being composed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159201/in-gmail-how-may-i-directly-forward-multiple-mails-into-an-existing-message-bei)

Comment: Thanks for the thought. It does... except "Check the boxes next to the messages that you want to attach and drag them to the new message window." is not possible in Conversation View. Also note that even outside CV, a draft reply prangs the drop.

Comment: Please do enter an answer so I can give you the vote and tick.